# Specifying test dependencies with the Gradle Android build system

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I want to specify dependencies for my tests and after reading the [Gradle Dependency Management Basics](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) I though I could just add `testCompile` calls to my dependency declarations like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.squareup.dagger', name: 'dagger', version: '1.0.0'


    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile group: 'com.squareup', name: 'fest-android', version: '1.0.1'
}
```

This, however, fails with this error message:

```
> Could not find method testCompile() for arguments [{group=junit, name=junit, version=4.11}] on project ':simstatus'.
```

Am I missing something here?

([Full gradle build file for reference](https://gist.github.com/passy/e142f3a1f44703d07b3a))

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The android build system doesn't use the standard Gradle Java plugin.

[Its documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing) says:

> As mentioned previously, next to the main sourceSet is the androidTest sourceSet, located by default in src/androidTest/
>
> Additionally, the sourceSet can be configured to have its own dependencies.
>   By default, the application and its own dependencies are added to the test app classpath, but this can be extended with

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2'
}
```

**Update**

> [As of May 2017 Doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html), `testCompile` is deprecated and you should
>   use `testImplementation`

```
dependencies {
        androidTestImplementation 'com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2'
}
```

Comment: This is correct. We are keeping "test" (as source set or dependency scope) for local jUnit tests (with Robolectric for instance)

Comment: @Xav: The Gradle usage seems to skyrocket thanks to Android. Thanks for that (I can't wait for Maven to be eclipsed by Gradle), and good to see the Android SDK Tech Lead answering questions on StackOverflow!

Comment: I missed this part in the documentation. Thanks a lot, @JBNizet.

Comment: @JBNizet: Hi, sorry for writing here, but I find myself trying to run JUnit tests that won't require android libraries and I'm not making it work. I try putting my `TestCase` subclasses in the `test/java` folder and call `./gradlew check` but they are not being ran. What is the correct way to run individual (non Android) unit tests using the android gradle plugin? Thank you!

Comment: I'm looking for such a feature too. For most part of my application, especially the problem domain classes, those does not requires a full Android environment at all and could just be tested on its own on my local machine.

Comment: Where exactly do I "add dependencies to the test app class path".   I've read this part of the guide a dozen times and I can't grok it.   Do I create another build.gradle file at src/instrumentTest?   If so which sections are needed?   I must be missing some fundamental assumption.

Comment: pzulw - you use instrumentTestCompile instead of compile command in a dependencies block. See the example above. compile adds a compile dependency, instrumentTestCompile adds a compile dependency for the instrument tests

Comment: instrumentTest has been deprecated and should now be androidTest.

Comment: As per javabeangrinder's comment - instrumentTestCompile has now been renamed to androidTestCompile.

Comment: @chakrit / LocoMike: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17431276/507339 for such a solution

Answer (score 3):

Just to make this question answered in full this is what is needed to resolve the issue. Since Junit is wanted for local testing and guava might be wanted for androidTest the android DSL should contain this:

```
android {
    :
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
                :
        }
        test {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/resources']
                :
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    :
}
```

*The : means other statements that you need. Please also note that the folders can be others than the ones above.*

Comment: From reading other comments these are the defaults though aren't they?

Comment: Yes, or at least they should be. Adding dependencies to testCompile is not possible without these though. At least for me. And that was what the question was about.