# junit testing with gradle for an android project

Tags: android, junit, gradle, junit4, robolectric

I am trying to get tests ( junit and robolectric ) working in an Android project but am totally stuck. My main problem is that all testing I found with gradle somehow pull in the java plugin and then I get this error:

```
The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.
```

The only way out I see at the moment is to split into test and app project - but I would like to avoid that. Any examples/hints would be highly appreciated!

In [the official documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) there is no mention of unit-testing - only Instrumentation-Tests - but I want unit-tests to get results fast.

Comment: Note that there is official unit testing support since AS 1.1 and Android Gradle plugin 1.1.0. http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don't need the Java plugin, since the Android will take care of what you need mostly, from what I've seen so far.

I managed to get my Robolectric and junit tests running via this man's blog: http://tryge.com/2013/02/28/android-gradle-build/

My build.gradle file looks like this (where my test files are in the {projectdir}/test directory.

```
...
// Unit tests

sourceSets {
        unitTest {
                java.srcDir file('test')
                resources.srcDir file('test/resources')
        }
}

dependencies {
        unitTestCompile files("$project.buildDir/classes/debug")
        unitTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
        unitTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.1.1'
        unitTestCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.0.1.2'
}

configurations {
        unitTestCompile.extendsFrom runtime
        unitTestRuntime.extendsFrom unitTestCompile
}

task unitTest(type:Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
        description = "run unit tests"
        testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
        classpath = project.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
}

build.dependsOn unitTest
```

Comment: thanks! does that work in combination with Android-Studio for you? Would love to run the tests from the IDE but that is not yet working for me

Comment: I don't use Android Studio yet. I simply run 'gradle build' from the  command line. Since AS has Gradle integration, and it runs 'build', it will also run the 'unitTest' task, so I would have thought it would be run, although I haven't tested this.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, I get classpath errors where my unit test can't find robolectric or junit. I'm running Gradle 1.6 from the command line with the task ./gradlew unitTest

Comment: I also can't get this to work. I get "package android.test does not exist"

Comment: Is this supposed to *run* the unit tests as well as compile?

Comment: Since Anroid Build Tools v0.11 the path for the class files changed. `unitTestCompile files("$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes/release")`

Comment: @Chris Should use debug folder instead: `unitTestCompile files("$buildDir/intermediates/classes/debug")`, but good to point that out.

Comment: I am using API 18, so com.google.android:android dependency won't work for me. Anyone knows how to refer to the Android SDK instead?

Answer (score 8):

AndroidStudio and the new Android Gradle plugin are now offering official unit test support.

This is supported from Android Studio 1.1+ and Android Gradle plugin version 1.1.0+

Dependencies can now be declared as testCompile:

```
dependencies {
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
}
```

More details here: [Unit testing support - Android Tools Project Site](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support).

Answer (score 1):

This guide might help -
http://www.slideshare.net/tobiaspreuss/how-to-setup-unit-testing-in-android-studio

Latest gradle the test should be under androidTest dir

Also in your gradle.build:

```
dependencies {
     androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
}
```

also add those under **defaultConfig** {

```
testPackageName "test.java.foo"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
```

}

Comment: Nope. If your unit test has no dependencies or only has simple dependencies on Android, you should run your test on a local development machine. http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use this doc
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html
It describes non-instrumentation unit tests that run on developer machine, not on android device.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me only:

```
androidTestCompile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-android:0.7.8'
```