# Robolectric test inside Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, robolectric

Is it possible to use Robolectric without creating a separate Java project in Eclipse? What I mean is can I have my test classes that are run with `RobolectricTestRunner` inside my Android application project. I'm asking this question because all tutorials I've seen make you create a separate project.

Comment: I'm not sure (I'm not eclipse user) but it should be pretty easy. And it is possible for IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio

Comment: I found this solution and it works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210810/junit-testing-with-gradle-for-an-android-project

Comment: @DanielRusev what you have mentioned  in the comment is for gradle based project but how come you run it using eclipse can you please clarify it.

Comment: I'm using the eclipse plugin for gradle