# Android Instrumentation test does not find classes from library project

Tags: android, android-testing

So I'm getting a `NoSuchMethodError` when running my Activity/instrumentation  tests from Android Studio, on the code line which tries to call a method in a library module from the unit test.

So this is my test:

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
    public void testMainActivity() {
        final MainActivity target = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        MyLibarary.someStaticMethod(); // yields java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
}
```

What's the deal here? I've defined my library as a "compile"-dependency in build.gradle, and it's compiling just fine. The library is also invoked from the main app classes without problems. It's only when I call it from the tests it fails. My app and my tests are in the same module.

I've tried running the clean task, the assembleDebug and assembleDebugTest tasks manually. No avail.

Project structure:

```
Root
 |---MyApp 
 |     |---src/main/...
 |     |---src/androidTest/...
 |----MyLibrary
```

Running Android Studio v1.0.2
Gradle build tools v1.0.0
Running as an "Android Test" on module "MyApp" from the Run/Debug configurations of AS with default Instrumentation test runner.

Comment: In Eclipse>>project properties>>Android>> make sure that the project you are testing is referenced under Library. 'is library' can remain unchecked

Comment: It's not really named either of those - I anonymized the code for SO. But that's not the problem - the code wouldn't have compiled if I had a syntax error. It compiles, but fails runtime

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment while you were responding.  Most posts on the subject say that you are finding two versions of the library, once during compile and another during runtime.

Comment: I should probably stop commenting.  I just saw you are using Studio and not eclipse. Doh!

Comment: I havent tried it myself but you could try adding a dependency in test configuration in android studio?

Comment: Well I alredy have `compile project (':mylibrary')` and if I add `androidTestCompile project(':mylibrary')` I get a bunch of duplicate class errors and compilation fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok this one was a bit tricky. Keyword: **proguard minify**. Since the newly implemented method so far *only* was used by the instrumentation test, proguard didn't pick up on its usage and therefore removed it from the DEX in the proguardDebugTest build step.

Solution: Either disable minification in the debug build (In gradle: `android.buildTypes.debug.minifyEnabled false`), or use the method in the main app.

Comment: ahh interesting. Didn't release the method causing the issue was not related to instrumentationTestCase. Good catch though!

Answer (score 1):

Not really up-to-date with `Gradle`. But i think we are supposed to specify the `testCompile` or the `androidTestCompile` dependency as well in the `build.gradle` if trying to write instrumentation tests.

Helpful Links:

http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

[Specifying test dependencies with the Gradle Android build system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637608/specifying-test-dependencies-with-the-gradle-android-build-system)

Hope this helps

Comment: Only dependencies *exlusive* to the tests, like junit, is supposed to be specified this way. My main app already has a dependeny through "compile" to the library, so it isn't necessary to reference it again. Solution was related to proguard though - see my other answer