# Robolectric 3 NoClassDefFoundError on Context

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I'm running **Robolectric 3 rc3** and I'm **unable** to run the **Robolectric** test due to this a `NoClassDefFoundError` on `Context`.

It was working well a week ago. I've found the issue listed [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=160024) which is posibly related but I don't want to downgrade AS.

Here is my config :

Module gradle :

```
// Testing dependencies
testCompile 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3'
testCompile ("org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc3"){
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
testCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
testCompile ("org.robolectric:shadows-play-services:3.0-rc3"){
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0-rc3'
testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0'
testCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp:mockwebserver:1.2.1'
```

Sample Unit Test class :

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class AdServerClientTest {

    @Test(timeout = 7000)
    public void testLongTask() {
        // Fails if the method takes longer than 7 seconds
        ShadowGooglePlayServicesUtil.setIsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(ConnectionResult.SUCCESS);


        assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

Exception below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/content/Context
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.hasSuiteMethod(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:20)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.collectWrappedRunners(JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.java:79)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.getClassesRequest(JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.java:51)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.buildRequest(JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.java:92)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.content.Context
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 16 more
```

**UPDATE :**

I've reduced the Test Class to only one assert and the Exception change to a Parcelable error.

```
@Test(timeout = 7000)
public void testLongTask() {
    assertTrue(false);
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/Parcelable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.hasSuiteMethod(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:20)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.collectWrappedRunners(JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.java:79)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.getClassesRequest(JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.java:51)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.buildRequest(JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.java:92)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.os.Parcelable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 28 more
```

**UPDATE 2 :**
I've run `./gradlew clean assembleDebug testDebug` and the result is that `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Robolectric does not support API level 22.`. Really strange because when switching to robolectric 3-RC3, emulateSdk and reportSdk has been removed : `@Config(emulateSdk = 21, reportSdk = 21, constants = BuildConfig.class)`. But have something to search for now.

Comment: Is there a reason `androidTestCompile` isn't what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637608/specifying-test-dependencies-with-the-gradle-android-build-system

Comment: @loosebazooka yes, the documentation say so https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/2.4-to-3.0-Upgrade-Guide#modules

Comment: @loosebazooka `androidTestCompile` is for `instrumentation` tests.

Comment: @HugoGresse why test the shadow `ShadowGooglePlayServicesUtil`? What other tests have you tried?

Comment: @JaredBurrows see updated answer, really strange issue, something related deeply in Android/Gradle/Robolectric

Comment: I have not used `timeout` with Robolectric before but have you tried using Robolectric 3.0rc2?  Also, what is in `GetAdResponseHandler`?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I was with RC2 when the problem appear first, I was thinking rc3 can solve but nop. GetAdResponseHandler is an empty Abstract class which implement a listener, not relevant here.

Comment: @HugoGresse Seeing that you have had this issue in RC2, then I definitely guessing it is something on your end. I have used Robolectric 2.3, 2.4, 3.0-snapshot, 3.0-rc1, 3.0rc2 and I have not seen this issue. I also have not found anything Github issues with Robolectric.

Comment: @JaredBurrows which version of AS and gradle plugin do you use ?

Comment: I do not use Android Studio. I use Intellij. Also, you might want to try to run your tests from command line: `./gradlew clean assembleDebug testDebug`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows thanks, see updated answer. I will try to use rc2 see what's going on

Comment: Just try to get it working with rc2 first with `@Config(emulateSdk = 21, reportSdk = 21, constants = BuildConfig.class)`.

Comment: @HugoGresse Do you have a library module? I have a similar issues sometimes with it. My solution is just to run first an unit test from my application module. After this I can successful run tests from my library module. I track this issue at https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric/issues/12

Comment: @JaredBurrows it's working with CLI on rc2. Not from AS.

Comment: @nenick yes my project I want to test is a library module. so you're saying running a unit test from the application module first, and next run unit test from library ? the first unit test (not gradle, junit) produce `Error:(3, 17) Gradle: error: package org.junit does not exist` with other packages not existing... The test run fine with gradle but I can only see the result from report, not within AS.

Comment: @HugoGresse Good. So Robolectric is working just fine.

Comment: Are you using a ".debug" suffix for your debug builds?

Comment: In such a cases you probably have to update android studio as well as gradle

Answer (score 2):

Change your Config in yuor test class to

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,sdk= 21,  manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
```

because `org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc3` doesn't support methods `emulateSdk` and `reportSdk`