# Unresolved class references with Android Studio in tests

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the annoying issue with Android Studio 2.0 beta 6.

I have multi-module project. And tests in one module (backend) are not compilable by Android Studio because it can not find references to classes from another module that it depends on:

[image: screenshot]

Everything is fine when I run **gradle**.

**UPDATE**

With **Android Studio** 1.5 I was able to run tests from all modules separately. I will investigate how to run all tests how it was before we were having flavours.

**UPDATE 2**

If I try to run unit tests from AS than I see classpath which includes:

```
**/core/build/intermediates/classes/test/debug
```

but doesn't include:

```
**/core/build/intermediates/classes/debug
```

Where are classes that missed right now

Comment: What about icpclient?

Comment: Do you use `androidTestCompile` in your gradle file? check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637608/specifying-test-dependencies-with-the-gradle-android-build-system it maybe helpful for you

Comment: @tinysunlight **icpClient** is fine since it doesn't have sources. This module is there only to wrap some dependency that is not distributed over maven repository

Comment: @vovaxo, I use plain unit tests. The answer is three years old from times when AS was not supporting unit tests on jvm

Comment: I don't really understand what you said.But I think you can try to clearcache and restart and put more clues.

Comment: @tinysunlight I mean **icpClient** doesn't have own sources. It is just module that keeps jar and so files. There is nothing to import

Comment: Can you  open a file in library core and create a screenshot  of directory structure of library core?

Comment: @tinysunlight if you're asking me to check if the file is there and AS understand it as project file then the answer is yes. I also updated the question

Comment: Do you use sourceset in build.gradle?I mean that default path maybe not same in different Android Studio Version.

Comment: No, we don't use any `sourceset` definition. As reminder it also perfectly fine works from command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had this same issue for modules in our project that had unit tests.  They all ran fine with the command line, but had this issue in Android Studio.  We finally determined it's a bug with the newest version of Android Studio.  The work around is to disable the "Experimental" test feature.

[image]

Hopefully they'll fix this in newer versions, but it's affecting us in Android Studio 2.0 beta 6.

Related Answer: [Test Artifact selector missing/gone from Build Variants in Android Studio 2 Beta 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708263/test-artifact-selector-missing-gone-from-build-variants-in-android-studio-2-beta)